# No code coverage generated from ReportGenerator in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, reportgenerator

I am using the [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) task in my **Azure DevOps** build to generate a code coverage report. The problem is that the generated report is empty.

In my **VsTest** task that runs the unit tests I have checked the option *Code coverage enabled*. The .*coverage* file is correctly generated and the unit tests are all successfully run. However, the generated code coverage report shows that no code was covered by any of the unit tests.

Here is a screenshot of my code coverage **Report Generator** task.

[image]

And here is the output from the code coverage report.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the **Azure DevOps** log file for the task showing that it executed correctly without any errors.
[image]

Interestingly the log does show the following

```
Analyzing 0 classes
```

Is this because **ReportGenerator** cannnot find the assemblies / classes? I've tried specififying a value for *Source directories* but this has made no difference.

Why is the code coverage report showing no code coverage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReportGenerator can not handle *.coverage* files.
You can find the supported formats here: https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator#supported-input-and-output-file-formats

You can use a tool like [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) or [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet/) to generate a coverage report in a format that *ReportGenerator* is able to parse.
Or you can convert the *.coverage* file format. Here you find instructions how this can be done: https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/wiki/Visual-Studio-Coverage-Tools

Comment: I've used coverlet previously so will look to use that. Thanks for the response, much appreciated.